# How can I run a scheduled bitbucket pipeline as administrator?

Tags: bitbucket

In Bitbucket Pipeline configuration there is an option available
"Only allow admins to deploy to this environment"
This feature is to protect the pipeline being executed from non admins.
But the problem now with this feature is that it also blocks the executions from scheduler even though I am administrator and I did schedule it.

So I just wonder if anybody knows a way to run a pipeline from scheduler under administrator rights?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like bitbucket doesnt support this use case yet. If you would also like to use the feature "Only allow admins to deploy to this environment" and at the same time you have the requirement to schedule deployments at night you can vote it up here:  https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-22893